# How to pass Parameter from Ajax to RestController in Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

i try to pass Parameter from Ajax to RestController to send a Email.

That is the Controller Post Methode to send the Enail

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String create(@RequestParam("covere") String covere, @RequestParam("title") String title,
            @RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("usernameto") String usernameto) {
        try {
            mailService.sendMail(covere, title, username, usernameto);
            return "sendmail";
        } catch (MailException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "sendmail";
    }
```

That is the Ajax to Call the Post and pass the Variable to send Message

```
$("#vuta").on("click", function(e) {
    var EmailData = {
              "covere" : "John",
              "title" :"Boston",
              "username" :"test@yahoo.fr",
              "usernameto" :"test@yahoo.fr"
           }

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/emailsend",
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(EmailData)
});
});
```

I have this Error when i send the Email

> Required String parameter 'covere' is not
>   present","path":"/emailsend"}

Thank for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is expecting parameters via **Query String**. You can use `$.param` to format the object as query string and send it in the URL:

```
$("#vuta").on("click", function(e) {
        var EmailData = {
            "covere" : "John",
            "title" :"Boston",
            "username" :"test@yahoo.fr",
            "usernameto" :"test@yahoo.fr"
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/emailsend?" + $.param(EmailData),
            dataType : 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
});
```

Comment: Glad to help :)